# Time Specified calls in Solidity using Oraclize

Tags: solidity, remix, oracles, recursive

I have started learning coding in Solidity and I have written the below contract using the official Oraclize guidelines.

### My aim is to:

- Make the *update()* function be called on its own on the specified time constraint in order to update the temperature measure.
- Get a notification of the update every time it is being called (maybe email or by any other means on a text file)

How should I configure my code to achieve this result ?

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
    import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

    contract WolframAlpha is usingOraclize { 



    string public temperature;
    mapping(bytes32=>bool) validIds;
    event LogNewOraclizeQuery(string description);
    event newTemperatureMeasure(string temperature);

    function WolframAlpha() {
        update();
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
        require(validIds[myid] ==true);
        require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());       
        temperature = result;
        newTemperatureMeasure(temperature);
        delete validIds[myid];
        // do something with the temperature measure..
    }

    function update() payable {
        if(oraclize_getPrice("WolframAlpha") > this.balance){
            LogNewOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
        }
        else{
            LogNewOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
            bytes32 queryId = oraclize_query(60,"WolframAlpha","Temperature in London");
            validIds[queryId] =true;
        }
    }
}
```

*FYI*

- I am using the online solidity compiler "Remix"
- Deploying the
  contract to ropsten testnet

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the execution of query as follows.

From the Oraclize documentation : -

The execution of a query can be scheduled in a future date. The function `oraclize_query` accepts as a parameter the delay in seconds from the current time or the timestamp in the future as first argument.

```
 // Relative time: get the result from the given URL 60 seconds from now
 oraclize_query(60, "URL","json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT).result.XETHXXBT.c.0")


 // Absolute time: get the result from the given datasource at the specified UTC timestamp in the future
 oraclize_query(scheduled_arrivaltime+3*3600,"WolframAlpha", strConcat("flight ", flight_number, " landed"));
```

From your question,you have to call the update function for specific  timeperiods.For this ,you have to schedule the call using JS.
On each call ,it will emit the event `LogNewOraclizeQuery`.You can do the watch on the event for notify about the latest update.

```
 var num=contractInstance.Result({},{fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' });
          num.watch(function(error,result){
 });
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I am calling the _update_ function after 60 seconds it has been deployed, **but only once**. How can I schedule it to run the _update()_ function **every 60 seconds** ?

Comment: EDIT :I dont care if i spend all eth of my account

Comment: You have to schedule the function call in JS. And on each call callback do the code to emit event.It can be used as notification using event watching.